# Nav-Framework is nice, however, it create fragment's view every time when people click menu-item on drawer-layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I use NavController + DrawerLayout, set some menu-items on the drawer, it seems automatically setup the drawer, it's cool. But, each time I click one item on the drawer and click the same item several times, the Nav will navigate to the same fragment and onCreateView will be called each time, it's so SAD! It's definitive a bug because the initializing of a view is not cheap.

Any idea?

[issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111631295)

Comment: It's definitely SAD. It's very common use case of any App with Drawer or BottomNavigationView.
Waiting for out-of-the-box support from Navigation architecture component

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Google says that it is expected behavior :

> We're looking more holistically at the Fragment API and will take this
>   use case under consideration there (since it is an important use
>   case).
>   source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109856764

So no resolution for the moment, may be with the next fragment/navivation version

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a bug using Fragment from androix package. Downloaded the sample app, that uses v4 package for fragments and the behavior that you described doens't happen.

Still looking for a fix :(